# Какой частью речи является слово "рассержен" в данном предложении?

Tags: синтаксис

"Лев был явно рассержен, что мы столь бесцеремонно нарушили его покой".

Answer (score 2):

Слово "рассержен" отбразовано от глагола "рассердить" и является в данном предложении кратким страдательным причастием, ибо, если судить по столь малому контексту, здесь на первый план выдвигается глагольность, а не качественный признак льва. В противном случае это было бы краткое прилагательное.
 Возможно, мне не хватает теоретической подготовленности в вопросах языкознания, так как теорией систематически занимался очень давно, и мои суждения зачастую основываются на "чувствовании" речи, но глагольность, по-моему, это такая характеристика слова,при которой на первый план выдвигается действие, а значит наличествует признак по действию, ЧТО соответствует идентификации причастия. Когда мой уважаемый оппонет приводит такие слова, как сердит, зол и т.д., то в них никакой глагольности нет, а лишь качественная характеристика, а вот "рассержен" - да, это связано с действием "рассердить".Кажется, так же примерно мы рассуждаем, когда пытаемся отличить отглагольное прилагательное "раненый" (раненый солдат) от причастия "раненный" (раненный в бою солдат).Извините за ненаучность моих рассуждений.

Comment: А не в данном?

Comment: >если судить по столь малому контексту, здесь на первый план выдвигается глагольность, 

Как это? Чем меньше контекст - тем больше глагольности?
Если не секрет, как вы вообще глагольность понимаете?

Comment: Ну что Вы придираетесь! Ясно же, что "малость" контекста действует не на глагольность, а на меру уверенности в суждении.

Comment: Да?
Ну допустим, а глагольность тогда что в понимании Виктора?
Лев был сердит, что мы нарушили его покой.
Лев был зол, что мы нарушили его покой.
Лев был гневен, что мы нарушили его покой.
Где тут глагольность появляется? Неужели же в пристаке "рас"?
Дело не в моих придирках, тут действительно грамматическая неразрешенность, дыра, по-просту. Отсылки к "глагольности" никак её не латают. Хоть в малом контексте, хоть в каком. Мне действительно интересно, как Виктор понимает эту глагольность.

Comment: Мне тоже интересно. Я ее (глагольность) как-то здесь не чувствую. Но, боюсь, @виктор1799, как и я, может неправильно понять Ваш вопрос из-за этой ссылки на контекст.

Comment: Самое забавное, что право быть прилагательными за такими вот образованиями от приставочных глаголов признали относительно недавно. 
Раньше их чохом записывали в причастия либо дифференцировали по косвенным признакам, далеко не всегда адекватным.
Но Лопатин вот признает без ограничения. И на этом основании и делает свои предложения по упрощению правил НН/Н в прилпагательных и причастиях.

Answer (score 1):

Если вас действительно интересует часть речи (а не член предложения), то тут такая ситуация.
"Рассержен" вообще может быть кратким причастием или кратким отглагольным прилагательным. Не всякое предложение позволяет оценить, с чем именно мы имеем дело.
Если по контексту понятно, что льва действительно рассердили и он **стал** рассерженным, то это причастие, если же речь идёт только о внешних признаках ("лев зол, гневен и рассержен"), то это скорее всего прилагаьельное. Исходя из того, что здесь имеется уиочнение причины ("нарушили покой"), можно предположить, что "рассержен" здесь - причастие. без такого пояснения я склонялся бы к прилагательному.

Большой разницы для мужского рода нет, будь это львица, определение части речи имело бы орфографический смысл.